Auto-generate element id / data-property from className
In my ReactJS app, I use SCSS modules and hashed class names that change with each deploy, resulting in something like this:
Header_mobileMenuToggle__6n6-W

I want to integrate a third party no-code tool that uses the elements' className to find an element and provide user onboarding. However, when I pass the class name with the hash value, it will break after the next deploy, because no such class will exist anymore.
I can provide the third party app with any css selector so I thought I could give it the elements' id or a data property. Thus, something like this in the built instance of my app would work:
<div className="Header_mobileMenuToggle__6n6-W" id="Header_mobileMenuToggle">...</div>

Writing the respective jsx like this in all of my code would be tedious and not worth the no-code benefit from the third party integration.
Question
Is there any way, like with some dependency / library, to assign the original class name, or the non-hashed part of the class name to the id or some data-xxx property automatically when building my app?

Please clarify, can this external thing only work with a class name, or does it accept arbitrary CSS selectors? If the latter - then you can probably just use an attribute-value-starts-with selector in this instance, on the class attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

The latter: any css selector (as specified in my question ). That seems to be working, thank you for the hint! Since this requires an extra step, I'll wait and see if there is any other solution.
